# Should I add runtime type guards?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on an app that has two parts to it, one "Admin" interface, and the other being an embed script that gets loaded on any website. Both projects are written in TypeScript.

Let's say for simplicity, the admin app generates this set of data:

```
{
  width: 4
}
```

The embed script requests that data when loaded. My question is, since both projects are written in TypeScript and are tested, is there a reason to add a runtime type check to ensure `width` is indeed a `number`?

I feel like it's redundant, since testing and at-compilation type checking for both projects should prevent `width` from being anything other than a `number`. Sure it wouldn't hurt, but would it be worth the time spent and extra code complexity?

My apologies if this is overly vague, but I can't really be more specific :\

Comment: TypeScript doesn't exist in production so all that type checking is just a luxury while developing. If you've already got tests written and you know exactly where that data is coming from and when/where it's manipulated, then you're probably good. On the flip side, if you're worried about types, why not write a `.validate()` function that checks your object before sending it off to be saved somewhere? That is, if you really need runtime type checking. Seems like this should be validated on the database/server side of things though (IMO). TL;DR sounds redundant.

Comment: I personally use `io-ts` on every boundary, regardless how trustworthy it is: any IO (cookies, local storage, ajax, DOM) in my code would be protected by an explicit type check.

Comment: @zerkms My issue is that my data payload is a lot more than just `width: 4`. Adding runtime checks for the entire data payload will add a lot of complexity, and considering it can't be changed outside of directly mutating the data through JS console or the database I'm not sure if it's worth the time spent. Do you have any insight into runtime type checking at scale?

Comment: @mwilson Thanks for your perspective :) I'm just worried about spending hours writing validation code that would never be used unless some bug somehow made its way past the pre-compilation type checking.

Comment: @Kyle define "scale"? I validate everything that comes into my application, it's the type safety question. "I'm not sure if it's worth the time spent" --- okay, I'm not going to convince you - to me type safety is important, if it's not for you - don't check it.

Comment: @zerkms Sure, my use-case involves about ten more properties on an object, with some of those properties having nested objects as values. 

I read the blog post linked from the `io-ts` repo and came across this:

"if we have end-to-end control over our application’s lifecycle then we could have ensured that any data source we are reading from at runtime would have ostensibly been generated by type safe code and therefore runtime validations would be unnecessary"

Since this is the case for me, I don't think runtime checks are necessary. Is it the case for you?

Comment: @Kyle I check everything as long as it crosses the TS boundary, regardless whether it originates from the same app or a third party: if anything changes I prefer to see the error on a boundary immediately, not somewhere deeply in the app.

Comment: @zerkms Right, that could save a lot of time and frustration later down the road. I think I might pursue that option. Thanks for your insights :)